# How to calculate the perimeter of an ellipse

Tags: python, math, ellipse

I want to calculate the perimeter of an ellipse with given values for minor and major axis. I'm currently using **Python**.

I have calculated the minor axis and major axis lengths for the ellipse i.e. **a** and **b**.

It’s easy to calculate the area but I want to calculate the perimeter of the ellipse for calculating a rounded length. Do you have any idea?

Comment: See also: http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/ellipse-perimeter.html

Comment: I've already visited there and get confused

Comment: a lots of approximation there which one is best to use any idea ??

Comment: @SagarGautam none of them is the best as you have to select approximation suited for your ellipse. Which one choose depends on the eccentricity of ellipse. You can also do the curve integral numericaly by transforming your ellipse to set of lines and sum their length ...

Comment: I've thought there is a simple equation for perimeter like area but it's complex process. I was wrong

Comment: If it's helpful, Sagar, I've coded the formula from mathisfun (in C) at https://github.com/gtoal/ellipse-perimeter/ - shouldn't be too hard to recode in Python or cross-call.  There's also a very accurate approximation provided there and code to compare the approximation against the exact (within floating point accuracy) calculation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Ramanujan's first approximation formula of finding perimeter of Ellipse ->

```
>>> import math
>>>
>>> def calculate_perimeter(a,b):
...     perimeter = math.pi * ( 3*(a+b) - math.sqrt( (3*a + b) * (a + 3*b) ) )
...     return perimeter
...
>>> calculate_perimeter(2,3)
15.865437575563961
```

You can compare the result with [google calculator](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=perimeter%20of%20ellipse%20formula%20a%20%3D%202%2C%20b%20%3D3) also

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have just checked above code and works fine

Comment: Does anyone understand know how to get this to arbitrary precision?  I was trying to understand the pattern of the coefficient numbers, but I don't know enough combinatorics.  1, 1/2, 1/8, 1/16, 5/128, 7/256, 21/1024 are the "0.5 choose n," but I don't know enough maths to understand why this is the case.  Perhaps I should post on mathoverflow

Comment: I would like to know how large the remaining errors with Ramanujan's approximation are.  If these are in the range of 1e-12 they probably are irrelevant in normal numerical applications.  If they are in the range of 1/1000 there might be cases where this isn't precise enough.

Comment: This is Ramanujan's 1st approximation which is pretty good. However, Ramanujan's 2nd approximation, as described in the answer by @Alfe is more exact. This approach can't be adapted to provide an exact solution, Nathan.

Answer (score 5):

a definition problem: major, minor axes differ from semi-major, semi-minor
the OP should be clear, those grabbing, comparing to online solutions should be too

[image]

you can get sympy to (numerically) solve the problem, I'm using the full axes definition

```
from sympy import *
a, b, w = symbols('a b w')

x = a/2 * cos(w)
y = b/2 * sin(w)

dx = diff(x, w)
dy = diff(y, w)

ds = sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)

def perimeter(majr, minr):
    return Integral(ds.subs([(a,majr),(b,minr)]), (w, 0, 2*pi)).evalf().doit()

print('test1: a, b = 1 gives dia = 1 circle,  perimeter/pi = ',
      perimeter(1, 1)/pi.evalf())

print('test2: a, b = 4,6 ellipse perimeter = ', perimeter(4,6))

test1: a, b = 1 gives dia = 1 circle,  perimeter/pi =  1.00000000000000
test2: a, b = 4,6 ellipse perimeter =  15.8654395892906
```

its also possible to export the symbolic ds equation as a function to try with other Python lib integration functions

```
func_dw = lambdify((w, a, b), ds)

from scipy import integrate

print(integrate.quad(func_dw, 0, 2*np.pi, args=(4, 6)))

(15.865439589290586, 2.23277254813499e-12)
```

> scipy.integrate.quad(func, a, b, args=()...
>   Returns:
>   y : float, The integral of func from a to b.
>   abserr : float, An estimate of the
>   absolute error in the result

Comment: No need for `scipy.integrate.quad`. Use `scipy.special.ellipe`.

Answer (score 4):

As Mark stated [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310956/how-to-calculate-perimeter-of-ellipse#comment71780168_42311671), you can simply use `scipy.special.ellipe`. This implementation uses the [complete elliptic integral of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind) as approximated in the [original C function `ellpe.c`](http://www.netlib.org/cephes/). As described in scipy's docs:

> the computation uses the approximation,
>
> *E(m) ~ P(1-m) - (1-m) log(1-m) Q(1-m)*
>
> where *P* and *Q* are tenth-order polynomials

```
from scipy.special import ellipe

a = 3.5
b = 2.1
# eccentricity squared
e_sq = 1.0 - b**2/a**2
# circumference formula
C = 4 * a * ellipe(e_sq)
17.868899204378693
```

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of a meta answer comparing the ones above.

Actually, Ramanujan's second approximation is more accurate and a bit more complex than the formula in Rezwan4029's answer (which uses Ramanujan's first approximation).  The second approximation is:

π * ((a+b) + (3(a-b)²) / (10*(a+b) + sqrt(a² + 14ab + b²)))

But I looked at all the answers above and compared their results.  For good reasons which will become apparent later I chose Gabriel's version as the truth source, i.e. the value to compare the others against.

For the answer Rezwan4029 gave, I plotted the error in percent over a grid of `2**(-10) .. 2**9`.  This is the result (both axes are the power, so the point (3|5) shows the error for an ellipse of radii `2**3, 2**5`):

[image: Error of Rezwan4029's answer]

It is obvious that only the difference in the power is relevant for the error, so I also plotted this:

[image: Error of Rezwan4029's answer over power difference]

What emerges in any case is that the error ranges from 0 for circles to 0.45% for extremely eccentric ellipses.  Depending on your application this might be completely acceptable or render the solution unusable.

For Ramanujan's 2nd approximation formula the situation is very similar, the error is about 1/10 of the former:

[image: Error of Ramanujan's formula]

[image: Error of Ramanujan's formula over power difference]

The sympy solution of Mark Dickinson and the scipy solution of Gabriel still have still some differences, but they are at most in the range of 1e-6, so a different ball park.  But the sympy solution is extremely slow, so the scipy version probably should be used in most cases.

For the sake of completeness, here's a distribution of the error (this time the logarithm of the error is on the z-axis, otherwise it wouldn't tell us very much, so the height corresponds roughly with the negative of the number of valid digits):

[image: Log of difference between scipy and sympy]
[image: Log of difference between scipy and sympy over difference of power]

Conclusion:  Use the scipy method.  It's fast and very likely very accurate, maybe even the most accurate of the three proposed methods.

Answer (score 3):

Use the improvement made by a russian mathematician few years ago (not infinite series calculation but convergence calculation using AGM and MAGM) http://www.ams.org/notices/201208/rtx120801094p.pdf  or
https://indico-hlit.jinr.ru/event/187/contributions/1769/attachments/543/931/SAdlaj.pdf
An use is there: [surface plots in matplotlib using a function z = f(x,y) where f cannot be written in standard functions. HowTo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69584390/surface-plots-in-matplotlib-using-a-function-z-fx-y-where-f-cannot-be-writte) (script for drawing a surface including isoperimeter curves: it means all X-Y from a curve are all half-parameter of all ellipses having the same perimeter). Or contact direct the mathematician, or buy at springernature.com the article "An Arithmetic-Geometric Mean of a Third Kind!",Semjon Adlaj, Federal Research Center “Informatics and Control” of the Russian Academy of Sciences, Vavilov St. 44, Moscow 119333, Russia SemjonAdlaj@gmail.com

Update from above: AGM and MAGM were rewieved in the above announced "convergence calculation" to better mathematical description called "iterated function". Here are below the codes for it. For full comprehension, the exact formula for calculating the ellipse perimeter is shown as picture. By using the "exact formula" term, we mean the user is free to define the calculation precision he want to stop the calculation (see the python code having it inside). With an infinite series it would be different: this is a "guess" when to stop the calculation steps.

```
#import pdb # for debugger
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np
import math as math


def agm(x0, y0): 
# return AGM https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean
    xagm_n = (x0 + y0)/2
    yagm_n = math.sqrt(x0*y0)        
    convagm = abs(xagm_n-yagm_n)        
    if (convagm < 1e-8):
        return xagm_n 
    else:
        return agm(xagm_n,yagm_n) 
    
    
# domains
#pdb.set_trace()  # start the debugger
N = 100
Wide = 10.
X = np.arange(0.,Wide,Wide/N)
Y = np.arange(0.,Wide,Wide/N)
Z=np.zeros((N, N))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        Z[i,j]=agm((Wide/N)*i, (Wide/N)*j)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
# fourth dimention - colormap
# create colormap according to x-value (can use any 50x50 array)
color_dimension = Z # change to desired fourth dimension
minn, maxx = color_dimension.min(), color_dimension.max()
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(minn, maxx)
m = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap='jet')
m.set_array([])
fcolors = m.to_rgba(color_dimension)
# plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
surf=ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors=fcolors, alpha=0.5, vmin=minn, vmax=maxx, shade=False)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('agm(x,y)')

ax.set_zlim(0, Wide)

ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.01f'))
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=10)
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 10, linewidths=1.5, cmap="autumn_r", linestyles="solid", offset=-1)
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 10, linewidths=1.5, colors="k", linestyles="solid")
ax.view_init(elev=20., azim=-100.)
plt.show()





#import pdb # for debugger
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np
import math as math

def magm(half_na, half_nb, start_p=0.): 
# start_p is minimum 0; but could be choosen as the smallest of half_nx parameter
#   when it has to be initiated. perhaps it speeds the convergence.
# return MAGM
# parution http://www.ams.org/notices/201208/rtx120801094p.pdf
# author MAGM http://semjonadlaj.com/
    xmagm_n = (half_na+half_nb)/2
    ymagm_n = start_p + math.sqrt((half_na-start_p)*(half_nb-start_p))
    zmagm_n = start_p - math.sqrt((half_na-start_p)*(half_nb-start_p))
    convmagm = abs(xmagm_n-ymagm_n)
    if (convmagm < 1e-10):
        return xmagm_n
    else:
        return magm(xmagm_n,ymagm_n,zmagm_n) 

# domains
#pdb.set_trace()  # start the debugger
N = 100
Wide = 10.
X = np.arange(0.,Wide,Wide/N)
Y = np.arange(0.,Wide,Wide/N)
Z=np.zeros((N, N))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        if (i==0.) and (j==0.):
            Z[i,j] = 0.
        else:
            X0 = ((Wide/N)*i)**2/math.sqrt(((Wide/N)*i)**2+((Wide/N)*j)**2)
            Y0 = ((Wide/N)*j)**2/math.sqrt(((Wide/N)*i)**2+((Wide/N)*j)**2)
            Z[i,j]=magm(X0, Y0)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
# fourth dimention - colormap
# create colormap according to x-value (can use any 50x50 array)
color_dimension = Z # change to desired fourth dimension
minn, maxx = color_dimension.min(), color_dimension.max()
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(minn, maxx)
m = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap='jet')
m.set_array([])
fcolors = m.to_rgba(color_dimension)
# plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
surf=ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors=fcolors, alpha=0.5, vmin=minn, vmax=maxx, shade=False)
ax.set_title('modified agm of (a**2/sqrt(a**2+b**2)) and (b**2/sqrt(a**2+b**2))')
ax.set_xlabel('a')
ax.set_ylabel('b')
ax.set_zlabel('magm result')

#ax.set_zlim(0, Wide)
ax.set_zlim(0, 8)

ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.01f'))
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=10)
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 10, linewidths=1.5, cmap="autumn_r", linestyles="solid", offset=0)
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 10, linewidths=1.5, colors="k", linestyles="solid")
ax.view_init(elev=20., azim=-100.)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Another variant according GAGM, see picture below, as iterated function https://pca-pdmi.ru/2022/files/16/PCA2022GAGM.pdf

```
#import pdb # for debugger
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np
import math as math


def agm(x0, y0): 
# return AGM https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean
    if (abs(x0-y0) < 1e-10):
        return x0 
    else:
        xagm_n = (x0 + y0)/2
        yagm_n = math.sqrt(x0*y0)   
        return agm(xagm_n,yagm_n)     

    
def perim_gagm(x0, y0):
# parution http://www.ams.org/notices/201208/rtx120801094p.pdf
# author MAGM http://semjonadlaj.com/
# https://www.hpmuseum.org/forum/thread-5820-post-171326.html#pid171326
    if (x0==0.) or (y0==0.):
        return 4.*(x0+y0)
    else:
        yN = math.sqrt(x0*y0)
        xN = (x0+y0)/2
        if (abs(yN-y0) < 1e-10):
            return 2*yN*math.pi
        return 2*(perim_gagm(xN,yN)-(x0*y0*math.pi)/agm(x0,y0))

#pdb.set_trace()  # start the debugger
#
N = 50
Wide = 10.
X = np.arange(0.,Wide,Wide/N)
Y = np.arange(0.,Wide,Wide/N)
Z=np.zeros((N, N))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        Z[i,j]=perim_gagm((Wide/N)*i, (Wide/N)*j)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
# fourth dimention - colormap
# create colormap according to x-value (can use any 50x50 array)
color_dimension = Z # change to desired fourth dimension
minn, maxx = color_dimension.min(), color_dimension.max()
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(minn, maxx)
m = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap='jet')
m.set_array([])
fcolors = m.to_rgba(color_dimension)
# plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
surf=ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors=fcolors, alpha=0.5, vmin=minn, vmax=maxx, shade=False)
ax.set_xlabel('ellipse halfparam a')
ax.set_ylabel('ellipse halfparam b')
ax.set_zlabel('ellipse perim')
Windo= Wide*2*math.pi
ax.set_zlim(0, Windo)
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.01f'))
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=10)
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 10, linewidths=1.5, cmap="autumn_r", linestyles="solid", offset=-0.1)
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 10, linewidths=1.5, colors="k", linestyles="solid")
ax.view_init(elev=20., azim=-100.)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are some good answers but I wanted to clarify things in terms of exact/approximate calculations, as well as computational speed.

- For the exact circumference using pure python, check out my pyellipse code https://gist.github.com/TimSC/4be20baeac7890e15773d31efb752d23 The approach I implemented was proposed by Adlaj 2012 (as suggested by @floppy_molly).
- Alternatively, for the exact circumference, use scipy.special.ellipe as described by @Gabriel. This is twice as slow as Adlaj 2012.
- For good approximation that is fast to compute and has no scipy dependency, see Ramanujan's 2nd approximation as described by @Alfe
- For another good approximation that is fast to compute (that avoids using square root), use the Padé approximation by Jacobsen and Waadeland 1985 http://www.numericana.com/answer/ellipse.htm#hudson

```
h = pow(a-b, 2.0) / pow(a+b, 2.0)
C = (math.pi * (a+b) * (256.0 - 48.0 * h - 21.0 * h*h)
       /(256.0 - 112.0 * h + 3.0 * h*h))
```

There are many other approaches but these are the most useful for normal applications.

Comment: Code in my answer above updated: the AGM and MAGM are in fact infinite iterated functions and it is now coded like this (the iteration is stopped when a "good enough" predefined precision is achieved). see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function  or good article here http://www.geometer.org/mathcircles/iterated.pdf

Comment: Code added above: it reflect the GAGM https://pca-pdmi.ru/2022/files/16/PCA2022GAGM.pdf (as iterated functions with exit criteria 1E-10 local agm precision for not using too much python memory stack)